# How to show data from database in wordpress?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, wordpress

I am trying to add following code in WordPress, but I cant find the right way to do it. Please help me someone...

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM wp_posts");
$total_records = $results->fetch_object();
$total_groups = ceil($total_records->t_records/$items_per_group);
$results->close(); 
?>
```

It's work great nice if I use it outside of WordPress. But I don't know hot to implement this in my WordPress index.php

There is a lot of code in my theme so I can't give you exact code of the index page. But here is the main index.php file code

```
<?php

$is_filterable_index = is_home() && x_get_option( 'x_ethos_filterable_index_enable', '' ) == '1';

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div class="x-container-fluid max width main">

    <?php x_get_view( 'ethos', '_post', 'slider' ); ?>

    <div class="offset cf">
      <div class="<?php x_main_content_class(); ?>" role="main">

        <?php if ( $is_filterable_index ) : ?>
          <?php x_get_view( 'ethos', '_index' ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
          <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_index' ); ?>          
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php /*?>         
<?php */?>      </div>
      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>       
  </div>  

<div id="content"></div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what did you write in the template?

Comment: You should go through the Wordpress Codex, in Wordpress you don't make your own database connections. http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: Wordpress has its own methods for accessing the db http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Wordpress db connection. Try this simple code and adapt it for your needs.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM wp_posts";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
var_dump($result);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I am getting following output can you help to understand what it is actually? array (size=1)       
  0 =>       
    object(stdClass)[3661]      
      public 't_records' => string '1257' (length=4)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$total_records = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM $wpdb->posts");
$total_groups = ceil($total_records/$items_per_group);
?>
```

There are various methods depending on what you want to do with results (if there are several rows or columns, for example, you wouldn't use `get_var`)

I used `$wpdb->posts` instead of `wp_posts` in case someone changes the table prefix (eg in `wp-config.php`).

Comment: I am getting this     Warning: Division by zero

Comment: That probably means `$items_per_group` is not set.  But I've also updated the first part of the `ceil()` call - it should be `$total_records`, not `$total_records->t_records`

Answer (score 0):

WordPress defines a class called `wpdb`, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database.

```
global $wpdb; //global connection object 
$results = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM wp_posts" ); // The get_var function returns a single variable from the database
$total_groups = ceil($results->t_records/$items_per_group);
```

[check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Use global Wordpress db object

```
global $wpdb;

$total_groups = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM wp_posts");
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be by using wordpress post meta.Post meta's are built exactly for this kind of stuff. All validation and security features are taken care of by these functions, so you dont have to worry about anything. All you have to do is 
GETTING VALUES

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ); ?>
```

CREATING / UPDATING VALUES

```
<?php update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value); ?>
```

DELETING VALUES

```
 <?php delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value); ?>
```

Similarly you have meta values functions for users as well. Checkout the codex for further info,